# Scroll not responding to NestedScrollView in android

Tags: android

I am trying to make a CollapsingToolbarLayout. I have successfully implemented that. I have a parallax image in the CollapsingToolbarLayout. Outside the CollapsingToolbarLayout I have a NestedScrollView with 3 cards. When I scroll the cards, the CollapsingToolbarLayout collapses to show the toolbar and the cards move to the top below the action bar. But they are not scrolling beyond the action bar. Result of which is, that I am not being able to view the contents of the third card.

Am I missing something ? Here is my code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout                     
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="325dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/artist_image_profile_page"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_default_artist"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:transitionName="selectedArtistImage"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_video"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/background_light_color">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/video"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_text_dark_color"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/background_dark_color"></RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_releases"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/background_light_color">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/releases"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_text_dark_color"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_biography"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/background_light_color">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/biography"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_text_dark_color"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/artist_biography"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:text="@string/test"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

## Heading ##</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Inform the version of the libraries used...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have specified layout_height to the last two cardview (android:layout_height="100dp"). Replace it with "wrap_content" and it should work smoothly.